# Calculating next due date

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer

in SharePoint 2010 I have the following columns Date Scheduled and Frequency. I have a work order currently scheduled for 9/1/2015 and a Frequency of 1. The frequency column is based on weeks. So with a freq of 1 the next work order would be due 9/8/2015. Frequencies go from 1-52. What formula in SharePoint 2010 can I use to get me that next due date?

Answer (score 1):

Create a calculated column and use `=[DateScheduled]+(Frequency*7)`. Return as Date and time.